# Trouble with RunTime.exec("su")

Tags: exec, root, su

I would like to run some shell command from my application but when i run :
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(su);
I have got an error : su: uid XXXXX not allowed to su.
I do not understand why because I think my phone is rooted as in adb shell su is working.
Does anyone have an idea about whatpoint I am missing?

Comment: What is the functionality that you are trying to achieve. If you give some more information, it will be easy to understand.

Comment: I would like to connect adb through wifi. So I would like to setprop service.adb.tcp.port 555 and then adbd stop and adbd start.